# Удаление антивируса Avast

Tags: windows, установка

После обновления с ошибкой: "не закончилось обновление", Avast не запустился. После удаления менеджером пакетов и установки не запускается. Что делать? Если в командной строке, напишите, пожалуйста, команды.

Answer (score 1):

Можно принудительно полностью удалить аваст специальной утилитой с их [сайта](http://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте откатиться на точку, в которой система находилась до установки антивируса, с помощью средств [восстановления системы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B). Потом попробуйте установить антивирус заново с включив лог (если установщик идет в виде msi-пакета)

```
msiexec /i установка.msi /l*v С:\установка.log /qn
```

Вместо установка.msi должно быть название пакета Avast.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте деинсталировать через CCleaner и потом заново поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Если не справляется виндин удалятор, то я делаю так: захожу в Program Files, тупо удаляю папку, в данном случае Avast, затем открываю реестр и удаляю всё, что связано с авастом, если лень, то можно воспользоваться утилитой- чистильщиком реестра,например Tune Up, но в ручную нудно, но надёжно

Answer (score 0):

прогугли и скачай  aswclearХ.exe - где Х - версия твоего "аваста" ну, там, - 5 или 6 или 7...

Answer (score 0):

а как удаляли? через инсталлятор аваста или виндовое удаление программ? в инсталляторе аваста есть варианты установки удаления исправления,еще варианты через uninstall tool, папки из системы вручную дучше не удалять, может быть только хуже, хвосты от аваста в реестре могут повлиять на работу или установку других программ, еще как вариант [avast clear](https://www.avast.ru/uninstall-utility)